# Ruby - how to run ruby code on windows cmd

Tags: ruby

help me. actually i have installed ruby from RubyInstaller.org but when i run the script on cmd prompt like ( ruby mycode.rb) then error occurs ( no suck file or directory) -- mycode.rb  what is this ? and what is the solution ?
Thankyou

Comment: thanks for the reply but error is still there

Comment: i have intalled ruby , and verified by typing irb .but it doesnt running my code <Load error> appears on cmd

Comment: no , i am using sublime text and i have saved the file by name project.rb and when i run this code in cmd and type ruby project.rb , then error appears

Comment: The error message is clear. `mycode.rb` doesn't exist in the current directory (or just isn't readable). Make sure it does (`dir` to get a file/dir list and `cd` to change it). Also, please copy and paste error messages.

Comment: H:\Naqash Data\Studies\Imtiaz bro RUBY>ruby Project
ruby: No such file or directory -- Project (LoadError)

Comment: This is the annoying error , help help

Comment: What's `H:` exactly? A local hard drive? Also tell us the full path of the `mycode.rb` file. Does [`dir`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121.aspx) list it?

Comment: YES , dir is listing mycode.rb

Comment: i have posted full path of my H:/ drive where project.rb is located

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ruby (no matter which version), check the boxes 
"Add Ruby executables to your PATH" 
and 
"Associate .rb and .rbw files with this Ruby installation"

Now you can just type "mycode" and cmd will open it. You can also open it by double-clicking.

Comment: i have still the same error :(. but thanks for reply . actually the error is " ruby : no such file or directory -- mycode.rb <Load Error>

Comment: Try shift+rightclick in the directory => open command window here; In the command window that opens type "ruby mycode.rb"; Also you could open cmd normally and type "cd PATHTOTHEFILE" and then "ruby mycode.rb"

Comment: buddy , i am doing the same thing :( but i think there is an installation problem

Comment: In short: Go to the directory first.There you can open your script.

Comment: i dont have a dev kit yet btw.

Comment: It dosnt matter if you use an IDE. I am using Notepad too.